# Syntax Error: unexpected $end when using if/else if?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm getting an error from one of my controller classes and I can't figure out why.  The error is:

```
SyntaxError in TermsController#show, syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Here is terms_controller.rb:

```
class TermsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @term = Term.find(params[:id])
        if @term.id == 1
            @title = "Fall"
        else if @term.id == 2
            @title = "Winter"
        else if @term.id == 3
            @title = "Spring"
        else if @term.id == 4
            @title = "Summer"
        end 
    end 
end
```

My show page currently just consists of:

```
<h1> <%= @title %> </h1>
```

It's probably something small that I'm just missing - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue that there are not enough `end` keywords and it found `$end` (the token representing the *end of the file*) before it could find what it was looking for -- another `end`. (The parser token for the `end` keyword is either "keyword_end" or "Kend", depending upon ruby version.)

***Each*** `if` expression requires a matching `end` keyword.

To get around this, use [`elsif`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/) instead of `else if`. It is part of the same `if` construct and does not require a matching `end` (only the `if` requires the matching `end`).

```
   if x == 1
     "1"
   elsif x == 2
     "2"
   else
     "else"        
   end
```

Another option is [`case`](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Expressions_Case_Expressions.html) which works well if all branches check the same conditional operand (`x` in this case):

```
   case x
     when 1 then "1"
     when 2 then "2"
     else "else"
   end
```

If you *do* want to use `else if` (remember, each `if` starts a new `if` conditional construct) then make sure close *each block* that a `if` opens. I have indented the code to show this point better.

```
   if x == 1
     "1"
   else
     if x == 2
       "2"
     else
       "else"
     end
   end
```

Happy coding.

---

For the pedantic: there is also another form of `if`, which is `expr if cond`, which doesn't have a matching `end` as part of the syntax and the rules talked about above do not apply to it.

In addition, `if` and `case` are *just expressions* in Ruby, so it might be more idiomatically written like this

```
@term = Term.find(params[:id])
@title = case @term.id
   when 1 then "Fall"
   when 2 then "Winter"
   when 3 then "Spring"
   when 4 then "Summer"
   else "Invalid Term"
end
```

The `if/elsif/end` syntax can be used in the same way, but using `case` avoids the repeated mentioning of `@term.id`. Another option is to use a Hash to perform this sort of simple mapping -- or the mapping can be encapsulated in a separate method -- but that is covered elsewhere ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `else if` use `elsif`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this:

```
class TermsController < ApplicationController

  @@seasons = { 1 => "Fall", 2 => "Winter", 3 => "Spring", 4 => "Summer"}

  def show
    @term = Term.find(params[:id])
    @title = @@seasons[params[:id]] || "Invalid Season"
  end

end
```

Comment: In looking at your original code, you actually are using the terms id to get the season. It might be best to override the title attribute accessor in the Term class to return the right String.. could use the hash and lookup as i have here in the controller in the model.